# Passing element down to the stream

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'd like to pass file down to the stream, but in some intermediate stage I'd like to process it by converting it to stream of lines.

I have something like this:

```
Stream.flow(file1, file2, file3)
.via(processFileFlow)
.via(archiveFlow)
```

ProcessFileFlow looks like this:

```
Flow.create().map(file1 -> Files.lines(file1)).map(line -> {send(line); return line;})
```

I can create Pair of file and file line, to pass file down to the stream, but then archive method is invoked too many times, because file is duplicated as many times as number of lines in this file. 
I want to run archive flow only once for a file.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the fold[T](zero: T)(f: (T, Out) ⇒ T) method, which would allow you to reduce your (file, line) to for example a sequence of files again before the archive step is called.

Comment: I tried this, but it wasn't work like I expected so I eventually used another stream. Inside the main stream I created another stream and I'm waiting for its execution.

Comment: I'm looking at this again, but still cannot find a right solution. To use fold first I need to divide the main stream to substreams for each file, because I'd like to reduce lines only for a file that they belong to, so I'm using scan (to mark first line in a file), splitWhen to start substream for each file and then fold. So it's a little bit overcomplicated and what is more doesn't work perfectly, because after completion of last substream archive flow is not invoked for some reason. So all the files are archived except the last one.